# Search with phone number but last 4 digit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my method

```
def phone_number_last_4
   phone_number = self.work_phone
   phone_number[phone_number.length - 4 ,4]
end
```

and my field name is **work_phone**

For example : my work_phone is : 1234567890 - so that my phone_number_last_4 is 7890

I want to customer on phone_number_last_4 digit but that not a field so How can I search that have phone_number include 7890.

My Table name is : Customer

so - Customer.where("work_phone = ?", 1234567890) - This is working but

Customer.where("phone_number_last_4 = ?", 1234567890)  is not working

Help me Please

Comment: You'd be better off using `WHERE ... LIKE '%xxxx'` than storing a second copy of the last four digits.

Answer (score 4):

```
Customer.where("work_phone ~ '7890$'")
```

This is assuming you're using Postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

Separate from the question, you can do `phone_number[-4, -1]` to get the last four characters of the string in ruby.

Assuming you're using mysql, you can do a similar substring query based on the last four digits on the `work_phone` field:
`Customer.where("SUBSTRING(work_phone, -4) = ?", '7890')`